# cancel XMLHttpRequest from removed iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, xmlhttprequest

So I have a dynamically created iframe that loads in a CDN script that makes an `XMLHttpRequest` request. As I use strict mode with react >=18, the iframe element gets created, then destroyed, and then created again as the unmounting and re-mounting happens. So the request from the initial iframe fails and crashes my app with the error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'REDACTED LINK': Document is already detached.
```

So my question is - how could I cancel the `XMLHttpRequest` request that was made from a third-party CDN script inside an iframe?

P.S. There is a chance that I am wrong with my initial assumption of why the error happens, but I don't see any other reason.

EDIT: Or at very least how would I catch such error?

Comment: I'm afraid it is hardly possible unless the origin of an iframe is different from parent.
Just an idea. Can you make an iframe permanent and avoid its detouching?

Comment: @tetta No, not really, the whole point why I am using iframes is so that I could dynamically load/unload third-party scrips without polluting my dom. I essentially "unload" CDN scripts by destroying the iframe they were loaded into.
So now I am thinking either I somehow catch the exception and ignore it or I go dig through the loaded CDN and cancel the request manually from inside the iframe on cleanup.